# Update query with VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Iam trying to update records in sql through Excel . I have written down some code on a button in excel to insert and update records in sql server. I managed to insert records but getting error on update query . i have checked for solution on stackoverflow already but still getting error. Can anybody check what iam doing wrong in the following lines of code

```
  conn.Execute = "UPDATE dbo.EmployeeInfo" _
        & "SET Week= ('" & Week& "') " _
        & "Time= ('" & Time & "') " _
        & "DateFrom = ('" & DateFrom & "') " _
        & "DatoTo = ('" & DatoTo & "') " _
        & "Name= ('" & Name & "') " _
        & "Description= ('" & Description & "') " _
        & "Codes= ('" & Codes& "')" _
        & "WHERE Week= (" & .Cells(iLoop, 1) & ") 
       AND DateFrom = (" & .Cells(iLoop, 3) & ")
       AND DatoTo = (" & .Cells(iLoop, 4) & ") 
       AND Name= (" & .Cells(9, oLoop) & ")"
```

Comment: You need a comma between each "column = value", i.e. set c1 = 1, c2 = ...

Comment: Don't know VBA, so I can't say. I know SQL. "update tablename set col = val, col = val, col = val"

Comment: I have tried that but still getting error "Argument not optional"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a comma between each column...

```
  conn.Execute = "UPDATE dbo.EmployeeInfo" _
        & "SET Week= ('" & Week& "'), " _
        & "Time= ('" & Time & "'), " _
        & "DateFrom = ('" & DateFrom & "'), " _
        & "DatoTo = ('" & DatoTo & "'), " _
        & "Name= ('" & Name & "'), " _
        & "Description= ('" & Description & "'), " _
        & "Codes= ('" & Codes& "')" _
        & "WHERE Week= (" & .Cells(iLoop, 1) & ") 
       AND DateFrom = (" & .Cells(iLoop, 3) & ")
       AND DatoTo = (" & .Cells(iLoop, 4) & ") 
       AND Name= (" & .Cells(9, oLoop) & ")"
```

Comment: i have fixed the issue we should have single quotes ' ' around Where statement.